# How to open correctly a date in Pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, pyspark, time-series

I recently started working with pyspark on time series, I was working what is the correct to open timestamp.

From the same parquet in Pandas:

```
df=pd.read_parquet("my_parquet.parquet")
```

I get the minimum timestamp equal to 2020-11-30 22:58:53.309 which is the expected one.

From the same parquet in Pyspark:

```
df_spark=spark.read.parquet("my_parquet.parquet",
                            inferSchema=True,
                            header=True)
```

I get 2020-12-01 00:14:28.338 as the minimum timestamp which is incorrect.

Comment: spark may have updated the timestamps to the session's timezone. check a few rows in pandas and pyspark to determine if this hypothesis is true.

Comment: Thank you possible the original data are in utc time so it is possible, let me check I get back to you.